# Make a wide dataframe long and add columns according to another column's name

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-melt

I need to use some names of the columns as part of the df. While keeping the first 3 columns identical, I need to create some other columns based on the content of the row.

Here I have some transactions from some customers:

```
cust_id    cust_first   cust_last   au_zo   au_zo_pay   fi_gu   fi_gu_pay   wa     wa_pay
0   1000    Andrew       Jones      50.85   debit        NaN      NaN      69.12    debit
1   1001    Fatima       Lee        NaN      NaN        18.16     debit    NaN       NaN
2   1002    Sophia       Lewis      NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN     159.54.  credit
3   1003    Edward      Bush       45.29    credit     59.63    credit     NaN       NaN
4   1004    Mark        Nunez      20.87    credit     20.87    credit    86.18     debit
```

First, I need to add a new column, 'city'. Since it is not on the database. It is defaulted to be 'New York'. (that's easy!)

But here is where I am getting stuck:
Add a new column 'store' holds values according to where a transaction took place. `au_zo --> autozone, fi_gu --> five guys, wa --> walmart`

Add new column 'classification' according to the store previously added: `auto zone --> auto-repair, five guys --> food, walmart --> groceries`

Column 'amount' holds the value of the customer and store.

Column 'transaction_type' is the value of au_zo_pay, fi_gu_pay, wa_pay respectively.

So at the end it looks like this:

```
  cust_id  city cust_first  cust_last   store   classification  amount  trans_type
0   1000  New York  Andrew  Jones     auto zone auto-repair      50.85  debit
1   1000  New York  Andrew  Jones     walmart   groceries        69.12  debit
2   1001  New York  Fatima  Lee       five guys food             18.16  debit
3   1002  New York  Sophia  Solis     walmart   groceries        159.54 credit
4   1003  New York  Edward  Bush      auto zone auto-repair      45.29  credit
5   1003  New York  Edward  Bush      five guys food             59.63  credit
6   1004  New York  Mark    Nunez     auto zone auto-repair      20.87  credit
7   1004  New York  Mark    Nunez     five guys food             20.87  credit
8   1004  New York  Mark    Nunez     walmart   groceries        86.18  debit
```

I have tried using `df.melt()` but I don't get the results.

Comment: Check out `np.where()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```py
# assign city column and set index by customer demographic columns
df1 = df.assign(city='New York').set_index(['cust_id', 'city', 'cust_first', 'cust_last'])
# fix column names by completing the abbrs
df1.columns = df1.columns.to_series().replace({'au_zo': 'autozone', 'fi_gu': 'five guys', 'wa': 'walmart'}, regex=True)
# split column names for a multiindex column
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([c.split('_') if c.endswith('pay') else [c, 'amount'] for c in df1.columns], names=['store',''])
# stack df1 to make the wide df to a long df
df1 = df1.stack(0).reset_index()
# insert classification column
df1.insert(5, 'classification', df1.store.map({'autozone': 'auto-repair', 'five guys': 'food', 'walmart': 'groceries'}))
df1
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is this something you want?

```
import pandas as pd
mp = {
'au_zo': 'auto-repair',
'wa':'groceries',
'fi_gu':'food'
}

### Read txt Data: get pandas df
# I copied and pasted your sample data to a txt file, you can ignore this part
with open(r"C:\Users\orf-haoj\Desktop\test.txt", 'r') as file:
    head, *df = [row.split() for row in file.readlines()]
    df = [row[1:] for row in df]
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=head)

### Here we conduct 2 melts to form melt_1 & melt_2 data
# this melt table is to melt cols 'au_zo','fi_gu', and 'wa'. & get amount as value
melt_1 = df.melt(id_vars=['cust_id', 'cust_first', 'cust_last'], value_vars=['au_zo','fi_gu','wa'], var_name='store', value_name='amount')
# this melt table is to melt cols ['au_zo_pay','fi_gu_pay','wa_pay']. & get trans_type cols
melt_2 = df.melt(id_vars=['cust_id', 'cust_first', 'cust_last'], value_vars=['au_zo_pay', 'fi_gu_pay', 'wa_pay'], var_name='store pay', value_name='trans_type')
# since I want to join these table later, it will a good to get one more key store
melt_2['store'] = melt_2['store pay'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.split("_")[:-1]))

### Remove NaN
# you prob want to switch to test = test.loc[~test['amount'].isnull()] or something else if you have actual nan
melt_1 = melt_1.loc[melt_1['amount'] != 'NaN']
melt_2 = melt_2.loc[melt_2['trans_type'] != 'NaN']

### Inner join data based on 4 keys (assuming your data will have one to one relationship based on these 4 keys)
full_df = melt_1.merge(melt_2, on=['cust_id', 'cust_first', 'cust_last', 'store'], how='inner')
full_df['city'] = 'New York'
full_df['classification'] = full_df['store'].apply(lambda x: mp[x])
```

In addition, this method will have its limitation. For example, when one to one relationship is not true based on those four keys, it will generate wrong dataset.

Answer (score 2):

One other way is as follows:

`df1` is exactly as `df` with renamed names ie having the name `amount` in from of the store value

```
df1 = (df
 .rename(lambda x: re.sub('(.*)_pay', 'pay:\\1', x), axis=1)
 .rename(lambda x:re.sub('^(((?!cust|pay).)*)$', 'amount:\\1', x), axis=1))
```

Now pivot to longer using `pd.wide_to_long` and do the replacement.

```
df2 = (pd.wide_to_long(df1, stubnames = ['amount', 'pay'], 
    i = df1.columns[:3], j = 'store', sep=':', suffix='\\w+')
 .reset_index().dropna())


store = {'au_zo':'auto zone', 'fi_gu':'five guys', 'wa':'walmart'}
classification =  {'au_zo':'auto-repair', 'fi_gu':'food', 'wa':'groceries'}

df2['classification'] = df2['store'].replace(classification)
df2['store'] = df2['store'].replace(store)



 cust_id cust_first cust_last      store   amount     pay classification
0      1000     Andrew     Jones  auto zone    50.85   debit    auto-repair
2      1000     Andrew     Jones    walmart    69.12   debit      groceries
4      1001     Fatima       Lee  five guys    18.16   debit           food
8      1002     Sophia     Lewis    walmart  159.54.  credit      groceries
9      1003     Edward      Bush  auto zone    45.29  credit    auto-repair
10     1003     Edward      Bush  five guys    59.63  credit           food
12     1004       Mark     Nunez  auto zone    20.87  credit    auto-repair
13     1004       Mark     Nunez  five guys    20.87  credit           food
14     1004       Mark     Nunez    walmart    86.18   debit      groceries
```

//NB You could consider using `pivot_longer` from `janitor`

Answer (score 1):

one option for transforming to long form is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/); it has a lot of options, for this particular use case, we pull out multiple values and multiple names (that are paired with the appropriate regex), before using other Pandas functions to rename and add new columns:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

mapper = {'au_zo':'autozone', 
          'fi_gu':'five guys', 
          'wa':'walmart'}

store_mapper = {'autozone':'repair', 
                'five guys':'food', 
                'walmart':'groceries'}
(df
.assign(city = 'New York')
.pivot_longer(
    index = 'c*', 
    names_to = ['ignore', 'store'], 
    values_to = ['trans_type', 'amount'], 
    names_pattern = ['.+pay$', '.+'], 
    sort_by_appearance=True)
.dropna()
.drop(columns='ignore')
.replace(mapper)
.assign(classification = lambda df: df.store.map(store_mapper))
)

    cust_id cust_first cust_last      city trans_type      store   amount classification
0      1000     Andrew     Jones  New York      debit   autozone    50.85         repair
2      1000     Andrew     Jones  New York      debit    walmart    69.12      groceries
4      1001     Fatima       Lee  New York      debit  five guys    18.16           food
8      1002     Sophia     Lewis  New York     credit    walmart  159.54.      groceries
9      1003     Edward      Bush  New York     credit   autozone    45.29         repair
10     1003     Edward      Bush  New York     credit  five guys    59.63           food
12     1004       Mark     Nunez  New York     credit   autozone    20.87         repair
13     1004       Mark     Nunez  New York     credit  five guys    20.87           food
14     1004       Mark     Nunez  New York      debit    walmart    86.18      groceries
```